# One output for input of $n$-tuples using AND, OR, NOT

Tags: combinatorics, logic, computer-science, binary

Let $B$ be set of $\{0,1\}$ and $B_n$ be the set of all
strings of length $n$. How many functions can be constructed from $B_n$ to $B$ using
logical operators like AND, OR, NOT.

Help $\rightarrow$ Define a function using all the operations AND, OR, NOT. Which gives only one output for an input of $n$-tuples?

Edit 1: Am a beginner to discrete math. I know I need a function that will take up all strings and give one output to set $B$. I don't understand the hint provided regarding $n$-tuples.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried to calculate this number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not post above so I am writing here:

The total no. of such functions is $2^{2^n}$ because all functions can be expressed. Say you have an arbitrary $g: B_n \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$. List all strings in $B_n$ on which $g$ takes the value $1$. Then $g$ is simply the disjunction of all characteristic functions of these strings as explained above.

Comment: So in simple words, is it : for every element in bn we have 2 choices that it can lead to. That is why that many no of functions ? Does this take in account the tuple being taken as input? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes to the first question. Let me give an example to explain how to code characteristic functions. Say $g:B_3 \rightarrow B$ outputs $1$ when the inputs are $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1)$ otherwise it outputs $0$. Let $f_1(x_1, x_2, x_3) = \neg x_1 \wedge x_2 \wedge x_3$ and $f_2(x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1 \wedge \neg x_2 \wedge x_3$. Then $g(x_1, x_2, x_3) = f_1 \vee f_2$.

Answer (score 2):

The wording of your hint doesn't make much sense. The closest thing to it seems to be the following: For any sequence $t_1, t_2, \dots, t_n$ in $\{0, 1\}$, try writing a boolean function $f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ using and, or, not such that $f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) = 1$ iff $x_1 = t_1, x_2 = t_2, \dots, x_n = t_n$.

Comment: But if I make function for strings of length n, then that means there is one function. I need to calculate the no of functions possible. Am sorry, even am not clear on what exactly it is asking for.